# Create a movie that takes as less space as possible (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, movie

what is the efficient way to create movie clip of 1 minute graph evolution ( quality is not an issue) that will take the lowest amount of disk space?

Comment: Scale down your video to 1*1 pixel 0.01 fps, it will be very small (just to explain the problem with your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any modern video (distribution) codec will produce a very small file in this case, if it is fed with standard parameters. So you will be on a good way if you just create e.g. a H.264 clip in MP4 file format. The only tweaking option that makes sense in that case is the GOP size, but that makes seeking in the file slightly harder for the player.

A more detailled answer needs a more detailled question.

Comment: that tip actually solved the problem, thanks